# 100% CPU when doing 4 or more concurrent requests with Magento

Tags: magento, cpu-usage

Currently I'm having trouble with a server running Magento, it's unbelievably slow.

It's a VPS with a few Magento installations on it used for development, so I'm the only one using them. When I do 4 request all 2 seconds after each other I'm finished in 10 seconds. Slow, but still within the limits of my patience.
When I do 4 "concurrent" requests, however (opening 4 tabs in a row, very quickly) all four cores go to 100% and stay there for like a minute.

**How is this possible?**

I know that there are a lot of possibilities here, so any tips on how to make an Apache/PHP server go faster are also welcome.

It used to go a lot faster before, and I've also tried APC, but it kept causing problems (PHP errors, something with memory pools) so I've disabled it.

By the way, the Magento cache is off and compiling is also off. I know this makes Magento slower than usual, but I don't think a 60 second response time is normal for any Magento installation.

**Virtual hardware:**
4 Cores and 4096MB RAM
Swap is never used (checked with htop)
100GB disk space, of which 10% is in use

**Software:**
Debian 6
DirectAdmin and apache custombuild
PHP 5.2.17 (CLI)

If you need more info, please tell me how to get it, because I probably don't know how. I do know how to use the command line in linux and the usage of quite a few commands, but my experience with managing a server is limited.

Answer (score 2):

Magento is horribly slow when you disable caching.. more so on a vps since it has to parse a ton of XML files. The way it renders a page makes it very easy to add new things all over the page but it also calls for some massive sql queries and also loading xml files.

So you disabling cache means magento has to read those xml files on every request coming in. So each process is now competing for cpu and disk IO. On a vps disk IO is where your bottle neck will be 90% of the time. So 4 concurrent processes all asking to read a lot of xml files causing a lot of CPU wait on the apache processes.

if you do a `strace` on one of the apache processes as it renders a page in magento you will see all the xml it has to render.

I haven't touched magento in over 2 years but it was a nightmare to run a site with traffic so my company at the time ended up building their own software.

Comment: I agree with this.  Magento is often unbelievably slow.  Also check to see that your innodb buffers are large enough in mysql, and see if there is other mysql tuning you can do.  Magento can do hundreds of mysql queries on a single page load.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, it is recommended to follow 2x rule: 1 core = 2Gb RAM, 2 cores = 4Gb RAM, 4 cores = 8 Gb RAM. Yes, you said that swap was not used, but maybe increasing RAM is the option. Tip: To track CPU and Memory load history (not just current) I recommend using Performance Monitoring extension by PotatoCommerce.

Answer (score 0):

You should figure out whether you are waiting for Magento, the database or any subsystem in between. To determine this, run strace on your webserver/php processes with the -ttt flag. Each system call will be prefixed with a microsecond timestamp, so you'll be able to see how long your PHP process is waiting for the DB, DNS lookups and possibly other system calls.

Comment: Seriously? That is not the case - if the processes would WAIT, the CPU Would not go to 100%, or? Not sure - I am a Windows guy, and there the CPU stays low when you wait for the CPU.

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion is to run the [MySQL tuning-primer.sh](http://www.day32.com/MySQL/) script to ensure your MySQL configuration has a proper baseline configuration.

Figuring out your problem with APC so you can utilize it will also be a good expenditure of your time. Even just a 32MB SHM for APC will make a drastic improvement.

Have you done a baseline optimization of Apache and PHP, i.e. removing unnecessary / unneeded modules? Are you using Apache prefork with mod_php or Apache worker with php-fpm?